# How to make objects rotate the same using transform.rotate in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have several objects that pass through a circular trigger collider, I have made it so when the objects enter the collider they start rotating using transform.Rotate() and when they exit the collider they stop rotating. My problem is that every objects has a different rotation by the time they exit the collider. Is there any way to make them rotate consistently?

```
   void Update()
{
    if(rotate==true)
    {
        transform.Rotate(rotation);
    }

    direction = (carrot.position - transform.position).normalized;
    transform.position += new Vector3(speed * direction.x * Time.deltaTime, speed * direction.y * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Here is my code, I simply made it so when the object enters the collider, rotate becomes true and when it exits, rotate becomes false. rotation is a Vector 3 variable that does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try rotating the object within **FixedUpdate**.

This should give you some determinism.

Comment: _"You could try rotating the object within FixedUpdate.  Keep in mind **you have to use Time.fixedDeltaTime** instead of Time.deltaTime"_ - no you don't.  _["When this is called from inside MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate, it returns Time.fixedDeltaTime."](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)_, Unity.   Unity is good that way.